# MacTeX 2018 Beamer 3.50 beamerarticle problem

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

Moving from MacTeX 2015 and 2017 to MacTeX 2018 my LaTeX Beamer files have a problem. With Beamer 3.50 in MacTeX 2018, files producing article mode output with the beamerarticle package have error messages indicating something has happened to the loading of the xcolor package.

Section 21 of the Beamer manual version 3.41 in MacTeX 2017 (and earlier) describe a way of producing article and Beamer output from the same source text (and it is also in Section 21 of version 3.50 in MacTeX 2018). We have three files:

- MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main.tex which contains the source material and the part of the preamble common to both Beamer and article modes
- MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer.tex which contains the Beamer harness
- MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.tex which contains the article harness

In the Beamer harness I have the option to the beamer class of `xcolor={x11names,svgnames}`- in the article harness I have the `noxcolor` option to the beamerarticle package and in the file I load the xcolor package with the command `\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}`- I have done it this way since beamerarticle appears to not have the same xcolor option that the beamer class has to pass options to xcolor - in the past up to Beamer 3.41 with MacTeX 2017 this worked. Now with Beamer 3.50 I get an error compiling the article version saying that `\colorlet` is not defined - the beamer version compiles as before.

Here is a minimal article harness. MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.tex

```
% Structure of files based on section 21.2.2 of Beamer User Guide version 3.15

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer} 

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Commands particular to article mode % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Color % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% loaded here since Beamer loads it separately 
% and beamerarticle loads xcolor with an option override unless you use noxcolor option
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}

% End of Color % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------


% End of Commands particular to article mode % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Load main file
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% The *.main.tex file has commands that work in both article and beamer modes

\input{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main}
```

Here is a minimal Beamer harness MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer.tex

```
% Structure of files based on section 21.2.2 of Beamer User Guide version 3.15

\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,xcolor={x11names,svgnames}]{beamer}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Beamer configuration  % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Beamer theme macros  % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\usetheme[right,hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{\fill}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}

% End of Beamer theme macros  % (end)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------


% End of Beamer configuration  % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Load main file
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% The *.main.tex file has commands that work in both article and beamer modes

\input{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main}
```

Here is a sample main file with the main source for both beamer and article versions, MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main.tex

```
% The *.main.tex file has commands that work in both article and beamer modes


\usepackage{ifthen}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Preamble Packages & Macros % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------



% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Color, Graphics, Diagrams  % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% xcolor is loaded by beamer


% End of Color, Graphics, Diagrams  % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------



% Preamble Packages & Macros % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------



% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Meta data % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------


\title{MacTeX 2018}
\subtitle{Beamer 3.50 Problem}  % \subtitle only available with beamer
\author{Phil Molyneux}
\date{9 July 2018}



% End of Meta data % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Macros & Packages for this file  % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------


% End of Macros & Packages for this file  % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% BEGIN DOCUMENT  % (fold)
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{MacTeX 2018 / Beamer 3.50 Problem} % (fold)
\label{sec:MacTeX2018Beamer350Problem}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{MacTeX 2018}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Moving from MacTeX 2015 and 2017 to MacTeX 2018 my LaTeX Beamer files have a problem
    \item With Beamer 3.50 in MacTeX 2018, files producing article mode output have error messages indicating 
    something has happened to the loading of the xcolor package
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}



% section MacTeX2018Beamer350Problem (end)

\section{Creating Beamer and Article Versions} % (fold)
\label{sec:CreatingBeamerAndArticleVersions}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Creating Beamer and Article Versions}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Section 21 of the Beamer manual version 3.41 in MacTeX 2017 (and earlier)
    describe a way of producing article and Beamer output from the same source text
    \item We have three source files:
    \item \textbf{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main.tex} which contains the source material and the part of the preamble common 
    to both Beamer and article modes
    \item \textbf{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer.tex} wich contains the Beamer harness 
    \item \textbf{MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.tex} which contains the article harness
    \item This is described in section 21.2.2 of the Beamer manual version 3.41
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section CreatingBeamerAndArticleVersions (end)


\section{Dummy Section 1} % (fold)
\label{sec:DummySection1}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Dummy Section 1}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1
    \item Point 2
    \item Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section DummySection1 (end)

\section{Dummy Section 2} % (fold)
\label{sec:DummySection2}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Dummy Section 2}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1
    \item Point 2
    \item Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section DummySection2 (end)

\section{Dummy Section 3} % (fold)
\label{sec:DummySection3}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Dummy Section 3}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1
    \item Point 2
    \item Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section DummySection3 (end)

\section{Dummy Section 4} % (fold)
\label{sec:DummySection4}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Dummy Section 4}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1
    \item Point 2
    \item Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section DummySection4 (end)

\section{Dummy Section 5} % (fold)
\label{sec:DummySection5}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle<presentation>{Beamer 3.50 Problem}
  \framesubtitle<presentation>{Dummy Section 5}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1
    \item Point 2
    \item Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

% section DummySection5 (end)

% Uncomment below for bibliography
% \renewcommand{\refname}{References}  % default is References
% \nocite{}
% \bibliographystyle{myplain} % myplain is produced by natbib and merlin
% \bibliography{web,computing}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} % default is not in toc

\end{document}
% END DOCUMENT  % (end)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a copy of the log file for the article version, MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.log - the undefined `\colorlet` error happens fairly early on at about line 87 of the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.5)  11 JUL 2018 10:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.tex
(./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerarticle.sty
Package: beamerarticle 2018/02/20 v3.50 beamer input in article mode

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count89
\c@beamerpauses=\count90

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count91
\beamer@minimum=\count92
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box27
\beamer@modecount=\count93
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasearticle.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.st
y) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty
Package: translator 2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty
\beamer@argscount=\count94
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty
\c@framenumber=\count95
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 760.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.
sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty:117: Un
defined control sequence.
<argument>  \colorlet 
                      {fg}{black} \colorlet {bg}{white} 
l.117 }

? 

/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty:117: La
TeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.117 }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty:117: Un
defined control sequence.
<argument>  \colorlet {fg}{black} \colorlet 
                                            {bg}{white} 
l.117 }

? 
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks17
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count96
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count97
\leftroot@=\count98
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count99
\DOTSCASE@=\count100
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box28
\strutbox@=\box29
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count101
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count102
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count103
\dspbrk@lvl=\count104
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count105
\column@=\count106
\maxfields@=\count107
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
\thm@style=\toks23
\thm@bodyfont=\toks24
\thm@headfont=\toks25
\thm@notefont=\toks26
\thm@headpunct=\toks27
\thm@preskip=\skip46
\thm@postskip=\skip47
\thm@headsep=\skip48
\dth@everypar=\toks28
)
\c@theorem=\count108
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty)))
(./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer.snm)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def
File: svgnam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/x11nam.def
File: x11nam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to Unix/X11 (UK)
))
(./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.aux)
\openout1 = `MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-bibliograph
y-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-bibliography-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-environment
-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-environment-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-months-dict
ionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-months-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-numbers-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-numbers-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-theorem-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count109
\scratchdimen=\dimen112
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count110
\nofMParguments=\count111
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count112
\MPscratchDim=\dimen113
\MPnumerator=\count113
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 72.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 72.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
(./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.toc)
\tf@toc=\write3
\openout3 = `MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.toc'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 82.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 82.
 [2]
Overfull \hbox (7.28166pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 103--105
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.main.tex \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 which con-
tains the source
 []


Overfull \hbox (22.16222pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 105--106
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.beamer.tex \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 wich con
-tains the Beamer
 []

[3] [4] (./MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.aux) ) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4380 strings out of 492649
 67434 string characters out of 6129623
 159001 words of memory out of 5000000
 8150 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 8006 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,6n,35p,856b,258s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2018/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2018/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-d
ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on MacTeX2018BeamerProblemC.article.pdf (4 pages, 49666 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 22 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

My workaround is to revert to MacTeX 2017 where the error does not occur and the output is fine for both Beamer and article versions - however it does look like something has unexpectedly changed between version 3.41 and 3.50 of Beamer - has anyone else observed this behaviour ?

Comment: I think this might be a bug and reported it to https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: load the xcolor package before beamer

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Or don't suppress loading of the xcolor package by beamer in the first place:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 4/8/2018**

Meanwhile this problem was fixed in the beamer development version, see commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/486/commits/28f1a1dfd5b9b105d3d427e5889fe732351a922d

I assume this will be included in beamer versions >=3.51

Comment: It certainly looks like an unintended feature in the move from Beamer version 3.41 to 3.50 - would there be any reason that the beamerarticle package could not have the same mechanism as the beamer class to feed options to the xcolor package ?

Comment: @PhilMolyneux The only reason I can think of is "backwards compatibility". In fact beamerarticle feeds options to `xcolor` - options which are no longer supported by xcolor and thus are ignored.